# Hiding Table Rows based on value selected in multiselectBOx

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can i show and hide table rows based on value selected in multiselect?

For example i have below multiselecct box.

```
<select multiple="multiple" >
<option value="1">foo</option>
<option value="2">bar</option>
<option value="3">baz</option>
<option value="4">toy</option>
</select>
```

if the user select foo and baz from multiselect then then i am getting selected values as "1,3" in jquery.Now in my html i would only want to show table rows whose id is either 1 or 3.means all the rows will not be visible having id apart from 1 and 3.

Thanks in advance.any help would  be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to get the `val()` of a multi-select, you'd get a comma-separated list of all the selected values. So you need to get this list, split it into an array, and then loop through the array and take action on each value.

Something like this:

```
$('#test').on('change', function() {
    var numstr = $(this).val() + "";
    var numarr = numstr.split(',');

    $('tr[id^=row]').hide();
    $.each(numarr, function(i, val) {
        $('tr#row' + val).show();
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<select id="test" name="test" multiple="multiple" >
<option value="1">foo</option>
<option value="2">bar</option>
<option value="3">baz</option>
<option value="4">toy</option>
</select>

​<table>
<tr id="row1"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr id="row2"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr id="row3"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr id="row4"><td>4</td></tr>
</table>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MqPzb/

Read about the magic:

- http://api.jquery.com/change/
- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: actually i am using JqueryMultiselect so that is not working for me...please check this link for jquery multiselect http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: @Gautam See, that's the kind of information you really need to put in your original question so that we can help you properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the rows a data-value attribute and then compare the data-value with the options value.

Like:

```
<table id="table">
  <td data-value="2">Row 2</td>
</table>
```

In JS you need a click handler - s.t. like:

```
$('#yourSelectBox:option').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $('#table').find('td["data-id='+id+'"]').hide();
});
```

Can't test it right now (sorry) but here is a link for attributes selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ in jquery